# Почему если использовать ресурсы из AssetBundle, то имена папок формируются циферками?

Tags: yii, yii2

Почему если использовать ресурсы из AssetBundle, то имена папок стилей доступных из web, формируются циферками?
Это хэш? зачем он нужен? Как сделать что бы он постоянно разный был, то есть имена папок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AssetBundle обращается к AssetManager, а то в свою очередь создаёт папки в месте, которое будет доступно любому человеку (изначально скрипты лежат в защищённой от доступа папке), который подключается к серверу. Делается это скорее всего для удобства. Функция, которая вычисляет хэш для названия папки хранится в AssetManager. При желании можно задать свою функцию хеширования имён при публикации.
Для изменения хэш функции необходимо задать AssetManager -> $hashCallback. И он будет генерировать названия папок.